# Why does adding a char (from argv) cause a no-result in C

Tags: c, argv

first post (as you would know) and the form tells me that my title is bad and will get downvoted but I can't do better :) I've worked on this a bunch already.

I'm trying to cipher text by adding a number given in the command line to a string.

Why does

```
include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    printf("%i", argc);
    char k = argv[1][0];
    printf("%c", k);
    char * s = "a";
    printf("%c", s[0] + 0);
}
```

correctly print "a" (besides for printing argc and k)
but when the last line is

```
    printf("%c", s[0] + k);
```

it just prints argc and k and then nothing. I wanted it to print `20a` (when running `./question 0`).

( I tried

```
char k = 0;
char * s = "a";
printf("%c", s[0] + k);
```

and that does work :(  )
It seems like the fact that k is coming from argv is the issue but I don't have any idea why (not that I really understand any of this)
Thanks!

Comment: Please *show* (don't describe in free prose) your program invocation, expected output, and actual output. Note that when `argc` is 1, `argv[1][0]` is undefined. Note also that both `s[0]` and `k` are characters, adding those rarely makes sense.

Comment: What matters is not where `k` came from, but what value it has.

Comment: This question sounds like it is really just "what is the difference between `0` and `'0'`?".

Comment: whoops, when I run "./question 0" it should also print 20a but instead it just prints 20,

Comment: But the last code does work, when I add char k to s[0],

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add relevant information. "it should also print 20a" no it should not. It looks like you are confusing `0` with `'0'`.

Comment: "when I add char k to s[0]" but can you print that `k` character?

Comment: i think so, it prints a

Comment: No it does not, you are mistaken.

Comment: Take a look at [ASCIITable.com](http://www.asciitable.com/)

Comment: I'm working in the cs50 ide and I think it is working.

Comment: What is the purpose of `printf("%c", s[0] + k);`? It can't be correct. `k` is already a valid character (in your case, it is a character '0'), what can be the point of adding it to character 'a'? You never want to add to characters together, this operation logically doesn't make any sense.

Comment: I'm trying to cipher text, when argv[1] is a different number than 0 I wanted it to convert the text, This was a larger program I just cut out all the other parts but the last piece of code does work for, when I add two characters

Comment: `s[0] + k` will result in an invalid ASCII value for `k > 29` (e.g. if `k` is greater than the unprintable ASCII `(gs)`) See: [ASCIITable.com](http://www.asciitable.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`argv` and `argc` and `"a"` are all red herrings. They have nothing to do with the problem. The problem lies in not understanding the difference between two character values, `'0'` and `0` (the latter is aso known as `'\0'`).

In order to understand the difference I suggest experimenting with this program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
    char a = 'a', b = '0';
    printf ("as char: a=%c b=%c sum=%c\n", a, b, a+b);
    printf ("as int: a=%d b=%d sum=%d\n", a, b, a+b);
}
```

Use different values for `b`, including `0`, `1`, `'0'` and `'1'` and see what happens.

Comment: This certainly is the answer even if I don

Comment: I hate that "enter" automatically add a comment. \n 't understand this completely but now I'll know what I'm looking for.  Thank you.

Comment: Are you aware, Yehuda, that you can edit your comments?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the expression `s[0] + k` is that adding a letter and a number together (conceptually speaking, ignoring the data types for a minute) can easily result in a value that is past the end of the alphabet, and printing it out *as if it was a letter* isn't necessarily going to work.

Bonus problem: reading the command line parameter into a single character isn't giving you a value of 0, but `'0'` which has a numerical value of 48. You can't just pull out the first character from the string. What if the user runs the program and passes 10 as a parameter?

You need to make sure that the result of your calculation is within the bounds of the alphabet.

As suggested by commenters above, take a look at the ASCII table, and try using some character constants sich as `'a' 'z' 'A'` and `'Z'` to modify the result

Answer (score 0):

The answer is very simple.

The ASCII code of 'a' is 97.

Assuming only the printable characters in the arguments, the lowest printable ASCII code from the argv is 32.

97+32 = integer overflow which is UB - on ideone.com system it is -127

you can try yourself
https://ideone.com/D8DLcy

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    for(char x = 32; x < 127; x++)
    {
        char m = 'a' + x;

        printf("'a' +  %c = char value in decimal is:%hhd - and the char is%c\n", x, m, m);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the information you provided, it looks like you're implementing a simple shift cipher.  Note the use of modulo for cases where the input for k is greater than 25.

```
#include    <stdio.h>
#include    <stdlib.h>
#include    <string.h>

#define     MAX_STRING  16

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char        num[MAX_STRING];

    char * s = "a";
    int k;

    if (argc == 2)
    {
        snprintf(num,MAX_STRING, argv[1], 10);

        k = (int)strtol(num, NULL, 10) % 26;

        printf("%c\n", s[0] + k);

    }
    else
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"Invalid number of arguments\n");
        return(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    return(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```